# setting a globalization culture in unobtrusive true mode

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, unobtrusive-validation

In my Asp.net MVC application, i need to set the DATE TIME model field  culture as "it-IT". Normally this will take system culture but to to change this defatult one i have sets UI culture to "it-IT"

i have tried below code in my application to changes the Culture

```
<system.web>
 <globalization uiCulture="it-IT" culture="it-IT" />
```

but its works if UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled sets as false only. But in my application i have to maintain this value as true itself. refer below:

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Can you please anyone suggest me to set the globalization culture in unobtrusive true mode

My view section:

`@Html.EJ().DatePickerFor(x => x.Date).DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").Locale("it-IT")`

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = new maskEdit();
        model.Date = DateTime.Now;
        return View(model);

    }
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(maskEdit model)
    {           

        return View(model);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class maskEdit
{

    [Display(Name ="DATE CULTURE")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking. You do not _set the culture in unobtrusive true mode` If you mean you getting client side validation errors when you enter a date which is say `30/11/2015`, then you need to modify the jQuery validator (which by default validates based on the `MM/dd/yyyy` format

Comment: Yes. actually i want to post back the "30/11/2015" date value. But in chrome its didn't fire "httppost" method (in unobtrusive true mode) because of validation error. So I want to set the culture(which has dd/mm/yyyy) in my application itself,  so that i can  post the "30/11/2015" properly.

Comment: You need to modify the `jQuery.validator`. One way is to use the [globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin.

Comment: What is `@Html.EJ().DatePickerFor()`? Its not part of MVC so you using an extension/plugin.

Comment: its a third party DatePicker component. it will post the date value as "30/11/2015" since i have sets the dateformat value as "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: What do you mean _unobtrusive mode true_? - there is no such thing! If your getting a client side validation error when you attempt to submit, then you need to modify the validator as I have repeatedly said

Comment: it means "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" sets to true in web config file as i have mentioned in my code

Comment: I give up. I can only repeat the same thing so may times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on this. In my application i have added jquery unobtrusive validation. so in validation, date with format "dd/mm/yyyy" is considered invalid date. To submit the date value with format "dd/mm/yyyy", please refer the below code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.culture = Globalize.culture("it-IT");
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                 return this.optional(element)
            || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "it-IT")
            || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
});
```